# Axis adding extra padding for large domains

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

Getting a strange situation in d3 axis generation. While creating a bottom x axis using [d3.axisBottom()](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#axes-d3-axis) for ordinal domain values, adding extra padding in starting and ending point of ticks in the axis. Situation in which the [d3.scaleBand()](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleBand) domain has more number of values in it.

I guess the tick generation getting shrink with some threshold number of domain items.

Ticks are equally distributed with a average number of items, Once it exceeds the limit it shrink with padding on first and last ticks.

Correct explanation for the above scenario will more appreciated.

```js
var width = 400, height = 200;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);
  
var xAxisScale = d3.scaleBand()
 .domain([1,3,5,7,8,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,36,37,39,40,41,43,45,46,47,48,49,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,69,70,71,72,73,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,95,98,99,105,106,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,127,128,129,130,131,135,136,141,154])
    .rangeRound([10, width -10])
    .padding(0.1);
    
var xAxisScale1 = d3.scaleBand()
 .domain([1,3,5,7,8,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32])
    .rangeRound([10, width -10])
    .padding(0.1);    
    
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xAxisScale);
var xAxis1 = d3.axisBottom(xAxisScale1);

svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,20)").call(xAxis);
svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,60)").call(xAxis1);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity and to settle a minor dispute between @Gerardo and myself, would you mind sharing where the domain values in this post came from? Did you just make them up or what is their origin?

Answer (score 3):

The culprit here is `rangeRound`. This is the expected behaviour, and it is explained in the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#band_round):

> If round is specified, enables or disables rounding accordingly. If rounding is enabled, the start and stop of each band will be integers. Rounding is sometimes useful for avoiding antialiasing artifacts, though also consider the shape-rendering “crispEdges” styles. Note that if the width of the domain is not a multiple of the cardinality of the range, there may be **leftover unused space, even without padding!** (emphasis mine)

So, the solution is simple: use `range` instead:

```js
var width = 400,
  height = 200;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var xAxisScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(200))
  .range([10, width - 10])

var xAxisScale1 = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(20))
  .range([10, width - 10])

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xAxisScale);
var xAxis1 = d3.axisBottom(xAxisScale1);

svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,20)").call(xAxis);
svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,60)").call(xAxis1);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As for the first part of your answer: this is not going to work as the domain has signifcant irregular holes in it.

Comment: @altocumulus this is obvious. I was not trying to reproduce OP's sequence. Also, it's clear that OP just wanted a big sequence of numbers... that's what I showed him how to do.

Comment: I try to make as little assumptions as possible about what OP might have wanted. On the contrary, you could ask why OP should have made the effort to make up such an arrray just for the sake of having many numbers. This guessing has led to way too much frustration. There is enough space in a question for the author to explicitly express themselves.

Comment: Additionally, it confused me that you were starting off by talking about `d3.range()` and concluding with "use `range` instead". It may be just me, but, knowing your other answers, I am not overly happy with this one. No harm meant, just appealing to your skills as a teacher ;-)

Comment: @altocumulus Since the "instead" in the "use range instead" refers to rangeRound, I believe it's clear that this is scale.range, not d3.range. However, for the sake of clarity, I decided to accept your suggestion.